# Emacs cheat sheet that lists equivalents to everyday vim commands

Tags: vim, emacs, key-bindings

There were two things that I want to know how to do in Emacs (23.2, *nix):

1. Go to the first character after indentation in a line
2. Go to the first character that's the equivalent to a given character (an equivalent to vim's fx command that goes forward until it hits the x character; maybe `C-s` (incremental search) is the best way to do this)

But, I think it would be better if I had a cheat sheet that listed navigational bindings. Maybe Emacs (self-documenting) can do this on it's own. Is there a list of commands that are equivalent to vim's default commands anywhere? How about a list of navigational key-bindings in Emacs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. `M-m` (back-to-indentation) will do this.
2. You're right, `C-s x` is the way to do that.

Regarding a cheat sheet, try starting with `C-h b`.  That will show you all the active keybindings, and you can drill down to find out what each of them does in more depth.

The [ViKeys](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ViKeys) page on EmacsWiki should also be a good resource for you.

Answer (score 3):

Probably this will help you too:

[vim7-emacs21-cheatsheet of freezing hell](http://karl-voit.at/vim-emacs-cheatsheet_of_freezing_hell.txt)

(or others who find this question)

Comment: This link no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145291/smart-home-in-emacs) gives you a few alternatives for the beginning-of-non-whitespace function (with slightly different behaviours for comments and what happens if you do it twice).

Comment: Not sure I get the obsession with making one key do eight different things.  If you want to go to the beginning of the line, press C-a.  If you want to go to the beginning of the text, press M-m.  Easy.