# Emacs: how to jump to the first column which contains text?

Tags: emacs

I know I can use `C-a` to jump to the beginning of a line (column 1). Is there a way to jump to the column containing the first character which was put in? As an example, assume you have some indented lines of text. To edit the first word in a new row, you don't want to jump to the very beginning of the corresponding line but rather to the first word/visible character in that line (which might be around column 16 if you have two tabs of indentation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `(back-to-indentation)`. It is not bound to any key by default, I think. I bind it to <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-a</kbd> in my `.emacs`.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! When I executed it, emacs (24) told me that it is bound to `M-m`

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility, from [Smart home in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145291/smart-home-in-emacs):

```
(defun smart-beginning-of-line ()
  "Move point to first non-whitespace character or beginning-of-line.

Move point to the first non-whitespace character on this line.
If point was already at that position, move point to beginning of line."
  (interactive) ; Use (interactive "^") in Emacs 23 to make shift-select work
  (let ((oldpos (point)))
    (back-to-indentation)
    (and (= oldpos (point))
         (beginning-of-line))))

(global-set-key [home] 'smart-beginning-of-line)
```

Comment: I was just writing a function to do exactly this!