# How to move to the first word in the line in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

In Vim, `^` can move the cursor to the first word (non white space) of the line, for example

```
    The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

here `^` in Vim will move to T of The, but in Emacs, how to move cursor to the first word (non white space) of the line instead of using a series of M-b/f and C-a/e/b/f? Is there any existing command to make it?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Emacs the same thing is achieved by <kbd>M-m</kbd> (back-to-indentation).

Comment: There's also a similar command (`beginning-of-line-text`) that's not bound to a key by default. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/145359/8355) for a discussion of the difference.  You can rebind `M-m` to `beginning-of-line-text` if you prefer its behavior `(global-set-key "\M-m" 'beginning-of-line-text)`.