# 'Semantic' movement across a line

Tags: emacs, elisp

Consider the following line of Lisp code:

```
        (some-function 7 8 | 9) ;; some comment. note the extra indentation
```

The point is placed between '8' and '9'. If I perform `(move-beginning-of-line)`, the point will be placed at the *absolute* beginning of the line, rather than at '('.

Same for `move-end-of-line`: I'd find it more desirable for it to place the point at ')' if I perform it once, and at the absolute end of the line if I perform it a second time. Some IDEs behave like that.

I tried to implement this but got stuck, my solution behaves particularly bad near the end of a buffer, and on the minibuffer as well. **Is there a library that provides this functionality?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know of any library, but it can be done in a few lines of Elisp.

For the beginning of line part, the bundled functions `beginning-of-line-text` and [`back-to-indentation`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Indentation-Commands.html#index-back_002dto_002dindentation-1667) (`M-m`) move to the beginning of the “interesting” part of the line. `back-to-indentation` ignores only whitespace whereas `beginning-of-line-text` skips over the [fill prefix](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Fill-Prefix.html) (in a programming language, this is typically the comment marker, if in a comment). See [Smart home in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145291/smart-home-in-emacs) for how to flip between the beginning of the actual and logical line.

For the end of line part, the following function implements what you're describing. The function `end-of-line-code` moves to the end of the line, except for trailing whitespace and an optional trailing comment. The function `end-of-line-or-code` does this, except that if the point was already at the target position, or if the line only contains whitespace and a comment, the point moves to the end of the actual line.

```
(defun end-of-line-code ()
  (interactive "^")
  (save-match-data
    (let* ((bolpos (progn (beginning-of-line) (point)))
           (eolpos (progn (end-of-line) (point))))
      (if (comment-search-backward bolpos t)
          (search-backward-regexp comment-start-skip bolpos 'noerror))
      (skip-syntax-backward " " bolpos))))

(defun end-of-line-or-code ()
  (interactive "^")
  (let ((here (point)))
    (end-of-line-code)
    (if (or (= here (point))
        (bolp))
        (end-of-line))))
```

Comment: Could I ask you when why you use `let*` in the first and just `let` in the second function?

Comment: @Dualinity `let*` allows dependencies in definitions, e.g. `(let* ((foo 3) (bar (+ foo 2))) …)` binds `bar` to 5. This isn't actually needed here, `let` would have worked. I do need to enforce that `(progn (beginning of line) (point))` is executed before `(progn (end-of-line) (point))`; in Emacs Lisp and even in Common Lisp this is guaranteed even for `let`, but I prefer to write `let*` as an indication for the maintainer that the order matters.

Comment: I figured that it wasn't neccessary, but I do believe that these little indications will make maintaining code a lot easier in the long run!

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions that almost do what you ask:

In lisp code, you can sort-of do what you want, with the sexp movement commands. To get to the beginning of the expression from somewhere in the middle, use `backward-up-list`, which is bound to `M-C-u`. In your example, that would bring you to the open parenthesis. To move backwards over individual elements in the list, use `backward-sexp`, bound to `M-C-b`; `forward-sexp` moves the other way, and is bound to `M-C-f`.  From the beginning of an sexp, you can skip to the next with `M-C-n`; reverse with `M-C-p`.

None of these commands are actually looking at the physical line you are on, so they'll go back or forward over multiple lines.

Other options include [Ace Jump mode](https://github.com/winterTTr/ace-jump-mode), which is a very slick way to quickly navigate to the beginning of any word visible on the screen. That might eliminate your need to use line-specific commands. For quick movement within a line, I usually use `M-f` and `M-b` to jump over words. Holding the `M` key down while tapping on `b` or `f` is quick enough that I end up using that by default most of the time.

Edit:

Forgot one other nice command - `back-to-indentation`, bound to `M-m`. This will back you up to the first non-whitespace character in a line. You could advice this to behave normally on the first call, and then to back up to the beginning of the line on the second call:

```
(defadvice back-to-indentation (around back-to-back)
  (if (eq last-command this-command)
      (beginning-of-line)
    ad-do-it))

(ad-activate 'back-to-indentation)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips! But I'm afraid I already use both sexp-based (via paredit) and word-based movement commands.

Comment: An advised `back-to-indentation` might help then, I edited my answer.

Comment: It works great! I must say yours is a very elegant implementation. Moving to the end looks like a harder task though - see my comments at Dualinity's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote these two functions that have the behavior you are looking for.

```
(defun move-beginning-indent ()
  (interactive)
  (if (eq last-command this-command)
      (beginning-of-line)
    (back-to-indentation))
)


(defun move-end-indent ()
  (interactive)
  (if (eq last-command this-command)
      (end-of-line)
    (end-of-line)
    (search-backward-regexp "\\s)" nil t)   ; searches backwards for a 
    (forward-char 1))                       ; closed delimiter such as ) or ]
)

(global-set-key [f7] 'move-beginning-indent)          
(global-set-key [f8] 'move-end-indent)
```

Just try them out, they should behave exactly the way you'd want them to.

Comment: Hey, thank you! While `move-end-indent` surely covers correctly the vast majority of cases, it can stop at spurious parentheses contained at the comments. Likewise, if one took the approach of doing the work left-to-right and stopping at the first encountered semicolon, false positives (e.g. the string ";") could ruin the operation as well.

Comment: It occurs to me that one could leverage the parsing / string propertizing that is already done for us: one would scan the line left-to-right, and stop at the first character rendered as a comment.

Comment: I agree on the comment part. I realized it when posting (the comment characters).

Comment: Well, on the meanwhile two have been provided!

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```
(defun beginning-of-line-or-text (arg)
  "Move to BOL, or if already there, to the first non-whitespace character."
  (interactive "p")
  (if (bolp)
      (beginning-of-line-text arg)
    (move-beginning-of-line arg)))
(put 'beginning-of-line-or-text 'CUA 'move)
;; <home> is still bound to move-beginning-of-line
(global-set-key (kbd "C-a") 'beginning-of-line-or-text)

(defun end-of-code-or-line ()
  "Move to EOL. If already there, to EOL sans comments.
    That is, the end of the code, ignoring any trailing comment
    or whitespace.  Note this does not handle 2 character
    comment starters like // or /*.  Such will not be skipped."
  (interactive)
  (if (not (eolp))
      (end-of-line)
    (skip-chars-backward " \t")
    (let ((pt (point))
          (lbp (line-beginning-position))
          (comment-start-re (concat (if comment-start
                                        (regexp-quote
                                         (replace-regexp-in-string
                                          "[[:space:]]*" "" comment-start))
                                      "[^[:space:]][[:space:]]*$")
                                    "\\|\\s<"))
          (comment-stop-re "\\s>")
          (lim))
      (when (re-search-backward comment-start-re lbp t)
        (setq lim (point))
        (if (re-search-forward comment-stop-re (1- pt) t)
            (goto-char pt)
          (goto-char lim)               ; test here ->
          (while (looking-back comment-start-re (1- (point)))
            (backward-char))
          (skip-chars-backward " \t"))))))
(put 'end-of-code-or-line 'CUA 'move)
;; <end> is still bound to end-of-visual-line
(global-set-key (kbd "C-e") 'end-of-code-or-line)
```

Comment: Your implementation works perfectly but I'm picking Gilles' answer as the accepted as it is the most concise